# Simple Form Submit Code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to create a simple form with only an input textbox and search button.

A person would type in the search term in the box and press search.

All that will do is take their search term and add it to the end of the url.

So if search term is "good italian food" the submit button would send the user to http://domain/find/good italian food

Whats the simplest way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
      function Search() {
        var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword").value; 
        var url = "http://yourwebsite.com/find/"+keyword; 
        window.location = url; 
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="search">
      <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
      <input type="button" name="btnser" onclick="Search()" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**use javascript and html form**

create a form with a button and text box
in the post of the form call the javascript function to create the url with the user input text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function redirect(){  
    var s = document.getElementbyID("txt").value;
    var url="http://url.com/" + s;
    window.location = url;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type=''></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest using encodeURI() to make it 'safe'.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could override the action attribute within the onsubmit event: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/HUvs6/)**

HTML

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="send(this)" method="post" target="_blank" >
    <input id="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function send( form){
    form.action = location.href + '/'+encodeURI(document.getElementById('text').value);
}
```

Also, overriding the form action, or redirecting the user, within the `onsubmit` event will allow you to use a true `submit` button.

This gives the user the ability to just hit the `enter key` once they finish typing to submit the search without you having to write extra logic listening for the the enter key within the textbox to submit the search.

Comment: Thanks for this.  There is always a ? at the end of the url. How do i remove that?

Comment: oh wow, didn't notice that. If you set the form method to `method="post"` it should get rid of the `?`